# Error on getting the URL result of a Google search.

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA, and I figured that trying to code is the best way to code. Anyway, I am trying to code a macro that will get first URL of a Google search result, but I'm getting error `Object variable or With block variable not set` when search result is 0, and the remaining operations are skipped.  Here's the error image:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltHUL.jpg]

Here is the code I used:

```
Sub XMLHTTP()

   Dim url As String, lastRow As Long
   Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object, objResultDiv As Object, objH3 As Object, link As Object
   Dim start_time As Date
   Dim end_time As Date

   lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   Dim cookie As String
   Dim result_cookie As String

   start_time = Time
   Debug.Print "start_time:" & start_time

   For i = 2 To lastRow

      url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1) & "&rnd=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)

      Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
      XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
      XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
      XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
      XMLHTTP.send

      Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
      html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText
      Set objResultDiv = html.getelementbyid("rso")
      Set objH3 = objResultDiv.getElementsByTagName("H3")(0)
      Set link = objH3.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)


      str_text = Replace(link.innerHTML, "<EM>", "")
      str_text = Replace(str_text, "</EM>", "")

      Cells(i, 2) = str_text
      Cells(i, 3) = link.href
      DoEvents
   Next

   end_time = Time
   Debug.Print "end_time:" & end_time

   Debug.Print "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
   MsgBox "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
End Sub
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is simplified code for the same method.

```
Sub xmlHttp()
    Dim url As String,
        lastRow As Long,
        XMLHTTP As Object, 
        html As Object,
        objResultDiv As Object,
        objH3 As Object,
        link As Object

    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1)
        Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        xmlHttp.Open "GET", URL, False
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
        xmlHttp.send
        Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        html.body.innerHTML = xmlHttp.ResponseText
        Set objResultDiv = html.getelementbyid("rso")
        numb_H3 = objResultDiv.getElementsByTagName("H3").Length
        If numb_H3 > 0 Then
            Set objH3 = objResultDiv.getElementsByTagName("H3")(0)
            Set link = objH3.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
            Range(i, 2) = link
        Else
        End If
        DoEvents
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

In the zero result case, H3 is empty so modify your code like this to handle this case

```
  Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
  html.body.innerhtml = XMLHTTP.ResponseText
  Set objResultDiv = html.getelementbyid("rso")

  **numb_H3 = objResultDiv.getElementsByTagName("H3").Length**
  **If numb_H3 > 0 Then**
      Set objH3 = objResultDiv.getElementsByTagName("H3")(0)
      Set link = objH3.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)

      str_text = Replace(link.innerhtml, "<EM>", "")
      str_text = Replace(str_text, "</EM>", "")

      Cells(i, 2) = str_text
      Cells(i, 3) = link.href
  **Else**
  **End If**
  DoEvents
```

Next

Answer (score 0):

One simple workaround--though not the best--is to skip the error.

Try the following modification:

```
start_time = Time
Debug.Print "start_time:" & start_time

On Error Resume Next '--Add this part.
For i = 2 To lastRow
```

Other options include a *true* error handling part, something that returns a value when your search returns nothing.

Let us know if this helps.