# google search in macro

Tags: excel, vba, google-search

I need some modifications to the macro in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906993/error-on-getting-the-url-result-of-a-google-search), like the search result 1st link in column c, 2nd link in column d, 3rd link in column e, etc up to 5 or more links respectively.

Here is the macro

```
Sub XMLHTTP()

   Dim url As String, lastRow As Long
   Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object, objResultDiv As Object, objH3 As Object, link As Object
   Dim start_time As Date
   Dim end_time As Date

   lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   Dim cookie As String
   Dim result_cookie As String

   start_time = Time
   Debug.Print "start_time:" & start_time

   For i = 2 To lastRow

      url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1) & "&rnd=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)

      Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
      XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
      XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
      XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
      XMLHTTP.send

      Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
      html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText
      Set objResultDiv = html.getelementbyid("rso")
      Set objH3 = objResultDiv.getElementsByTagName("H3")(0)
      Set link = objH3.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)


      str_text = Replace(link.innerHTML, "<EM>", "")
      str_text = Replace(str_text, "</EM>", "")

      Cells(i, 2) = str_text
      Cells(i, 3) = link.href
      DoEvents
   Next

   end_time = Time
   Debug.Print "end_time:" & end_time

   Debug.Print "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
   MsgBox "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to put each Hyperlink in row 1, column C et Seq., modify these lines:

```
Cells(i, 2) = str_text
Cells(i, 3) = link.href
```

and change them to this one line:

```
Cells(1, i+2) = link.href
```

The statement `Cells(r, c)` indicates the *row* and *column* position to be assigned, so while the code initially was putting each result & link on a new line, in columns B and C (`Cells(i, 2)` would be column B, etc.) you just need to modify that statement to put the data where you want it.