# Returning first URL of Google search VBA Run-Time error 91: Object variable not set

Tags: vba, xmlhttprequest

Excel 2010
Windows 7 64

Hi I am aware that there is a page with the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906993/error-on-getting-the-url-result-of-a-google-search) but it did not have an answer that worked. I tried the alternative codes and modifications and with the code from user3450151 the error returned was 'Access is denied'. 
I am trying to understand where the problem is occurring as the code suddenly stopped working but nothing had changed, so I think it might be a permissions issue and don't know how to change it. Here is the code I am using:

```
Sub XMLHTTP()

    Dim url As String, lastRow As Long
    Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object, objResultDiv As Object, objH3 As Object, link As Object
    Dim start_time As Date
    Dim end_time As Date

    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim cookie As String
    Dim result_cookie As String

    start_time = Time
    Debug.Print "start_time:" & start_time

    For i = 2 To lastRow

        url = "https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=" & Cells(i, 2) & "&rnd=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)

        Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
        XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
        XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
        XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
        XMLHTTP.send

            Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText
        Set objResultDiv = html.getelementbyid("rso")
        Set objH3 = objResultDiv.getelementsbytagname("H3")(0)
        Set link = objH3.getelementsbytagname("a")(0)


        str_text = Replace(link.innerHTML, "<EM>", "")
        str_text = Replace(str_text, "</EM>", "")

        Cells(i, 2) = str_text
        Cells(i, 3) = link.href
        DoEvents
    Next

    end_time = Time
    Debug.Print "end_time:" & end_time

    Debug.Print "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
    MsgBox "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
End Sub
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what might be stopping this from working?..

EDIT:

```
Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
        XMLHTTP.setProxy 2, "http://127.0.0.1:8888", ""
        XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
        XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
        XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
        XMLHTTP.send
```

@Ian Montgomery Runtime error 438 on the new line

Comment: Where does it bring up the error?

Comment: `Set objH3 = objResultDiv.getelementsbytagname("H3")(0)`

Comment: In the loop does it run at least once?

Comment: It doesn't run at all, well if the column has no values it displays the complete dialog box and not the error...

Comment: In the locals window when I step through there are no variables when it executes that line....

Comment: Get and install Fiddler ([link](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)), set the HMLHTTP object to use Fiddler as proxy: `XMLHTTP.setProxy 2, "http://127.0.0.1:8888", ""`, run your macro and inspect the server response in Fiddler.

Comment: Do I insert it before XMLHTTP.send and after user agent?

Comment: In current position the error is given - Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: @ThomasSharp any place after you create the XMLHTTP object and before you call its Send method. I just tried your code, it does work.

Comment: @IanMontgomery Edited OP

Comment: The code just ran through 6 times then stopped.

Comment: @ThomasSharp try to change the request object to this: `Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")`. This should allow you to call setProxy method.

Comment: Set objResultDiv = html.getelementbyid("rso") returns nothing which is why you get the error in the next line.    Try adding in some error logic to deal with it and it will most likely resolve your issue.

Comment: Hi, I've discovered that this is not to do with VBA at all, Google must block your IP after regular searching as if you wait 2-3 hours the code runs again